# VS code slow for a specific project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

I've been using VS coed for some years now and I loved the experience so far, but one of my most recent projects is suddenly slowdowns the VS code drastically, I couldn't figure out why yet. And amazingly other projects do not give me this headache at the moment, with VS code. So I suspect there's something with the particular project I was mentioned before giving me the trouble. I tried deleting the repo and cloning it again in a new place, uninstalled and installed VS code again, but still no luck. It's really laggy, It takes upto a minute or so to update something I wrote in the editor.

Here's the status report of VS code when the problem occurs

```
Version:          Code 1.63.0 (7db1a2b88f7557e0a43fec75b6ba7e50b3e9f77e, 2021-12-07T05:15:48.091Z)
OS Version:       Darwin arm64 20.6.0
CPUs:             Apple M1 (8 x 24)
Memory (System):  8.00GB (0.16GB free)
Load (avg):       5, 3, 3
VM:               0%
Screen Reader:    no
Process Argv:     . --crash-reporter-id 135db0ac-bedd-440b-a1f5-305e8d0da10a
GPU Status:       2d_canvas:                  enabled
                  gpu_compositing:            enabled
                  metal:                      disabled_off
                  multiple_raster_threads:    enabled_on
                  oop_rasterization:          enabled
                  opengl:                     enabled_on
                  rasterization:              enabled
                  skia_renderer:              disabled_off_ok
                  video_decode:               enabled
                  webgl:                      enabled
                  webgl2:                     enabled

CPU %   Mem MB     PID  Process
    0       49   68581  code main
    0        8   68584     gpu-process
    0        0   68586     utility-network-service
    0       25   68587     window (Home.module.scss — intl_rail_frontend)
    0        8   68589     extensionHost
    0        8   68592       /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/css-language-features/server/dist/node/cssServerMain --node-ipc --clientProcessId=68589
    0        8   68593       /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Users/saniranimantha/.vscode/extensions/mrmlnc.vscode-scss-0.10.0/out/unsafe/server.js --node-ipc --clientProcessId=68589
    0        8   68599       /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Users/saniranimantha/.vscode/extensions/pranaygp.vscode-css-peek-4.2.0/server/out/server.js --node-ipc --clientProcessId=68589
    0        8   68647       /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Users/saniranimantha/.vscode/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.2.2/server/out/eslintServer.js --node-ipc --clientProcessId=68589
    0        8   68649       /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node --max-old-space-size=3072 /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js --serverMode partialSemantic --useInferredProjectPerProjectRoot --disableAutomaticTypingAcquisition --cancellationPipeName /var/folders/rq/blr_6bns4jj55p5v39b9944c0000gn/T/vscode-typescript501/0deafbb1814f87b4a9d0/tscancellation-203b3170cd2db589cca5.tmp* --globalPlugins typescript-tslint-plugin --pluginProbeLocations /Users/saniranimantha/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin-1.3.3 --locale en --noGetErrOnBackgroundUpdate --validateDefaultNpmLocation
    0        8   68650       /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node --max-old-space-size=3072 /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js --useInferredProjectPerProjectRoot --enableTelemetry --cancellationPipeName /var/folders/rq/blr_6bns4jj55p5v39b9944c0000gn/T/vscode-typescript501/0deafbb1814f87b4a9d0/tscancellation-38ad42b6e6229c3acf14.tmp* --globalPlugins typescript-tslint-plugin --pluginProbeLocations /Users/saniranimantha/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin-1.3.3 --locale en --noGetErrOnBackgroundUpdate --validateDefaultNpmLocation
    0        0   68657         /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/typingsInstaller.js --globalTypingsCacheLocation /Users/saniranimantha/Library/Caches/typescript/4.5 --enableTelemetry --typesMapLocation /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/typesMap.json --validateDefaultNpmLocation
    0        0   68884       /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/html-language-features/server/dist/node/htmlServerMain --node-ipc --clientProcessId=68589
    0        8   68590     shared-process
    0        0   68614       ptyHost
    0        8   68616       watcherServiceParcelSharedProcess

Workspace Stats: 
|  Window (Home.module.scss — intl_rail_frontend)
|    Folder (intl_rail_frontend): 1059 files
|      File types: js(252) json(163) ts(89) tsx(69) woff(52) eot(52) pack(47)
|                  scss(32) png(30) map(28)
|      Conf files: package.json(9) tsconfig.json(4) settings.json(1)
```

I'm using Mac with M1 chip, and macOS is Big Sur v11.6

Comment: same issue started now after today's update

Comment: I also have the exact same issue but in windows 11

Comment: seems nobody has answer to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same issue with VSCode and decided to download the latest version of VSCode Insiders (https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/). They seem to have fixed this issue as the problem is not showing up anymore on any of the affected projects.

You can also sync your VSCode settings with VSCode Insiders (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync) so you can continue to work normally until this issue is fixed in regular VSCode.

Comment: hey, this solves the issue, I removed all the vs code related items from the mac and installed the insiders version. unfortunately, the extensions did not sync, but It won't matter as far as I can code speed, I could install extensions manually though.

Comment: Great this works out for you aswell! It's not necessary to remove classic vs code though. Insiders and vscode work perfectly fine on the same machine.